# bluej program that returns all characters up to the first @ sign

Tags: java, bluej

```
public class IndexOf_SOL
{  

    /*
     *method getFirstChunk() should return
     *all letters up to the first @ sign
     */
    public static String getLastChunk( String line )
    {
        int loc2 = line.lastIndexOf("@");

        return line.substring(loc2);
    }
    public static String getMiddleChunk( String line )
    {
        int loc1= line.indexOf("@");
        int loc3 = line.lastIndexOf("@");

        return line.substring(loc1,loc3);

    }
    public static String getFirstChunk( String line )
    {
        int loc = line.indexOf("@");
        return line.substring(0,loc);

    }


}
```

When i do it in order from last,middle, to first chunk 
I get @big@areElephants
 When I am suppose to be getting bigareElephants without the @ sign

Comment: Why don't you use Tokenizer ?

Comment: I am not familiarized. It is my first time taking a computer science class and it happens to be AP so I am struggling a bit. Do you use Bluej?

Comment: See my answer! It explains how to do it !

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try the edited piece of code!

Comment: I can't seem to be able to split the @ sign

Comment: The edited portion in my answer helps split the String whenever it encounters the @ symbol. 

Try running the EDITed code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
String[] parts = str.split("@");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT** :

```
public class IndexOf_SOL
{  

    public static void main(String args[])
     {
       String str = "AP@computer@science";
       String[] parts = str.split("@");
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
        System.out.println(parts[i]);
       }
     }


}
```

Try the code after edit ! 
Hope it helps!!